# XAMPP server behaving strange

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have XAMPP V 1.7.7 containing Apache 2.2.21 installed on Windows Server 2008 R2. The issue is quite strange. There is a frame.php which consists two different frames.

```
 <FRAMESET name='mainframe' rows="40%, 60%">
      <FRAME src="description.php" name="des">
      <FRAME src="groupnames.php" name="grouping">
  </FRAMESET>
```

Second frame is loading properly but first one "description.php" is behaving strange. Sometimes it loads, and sometimes it doesn't. The issue is on production server, not on my local machine. I admit that I am not using XAMPP on local machine. It is MAC so I have inbuilt Apache.
 Here is the code for description.php:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="../js/main.js"></SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<?php
     include_once '../classes/utils.php';
     include_once ("../classes/brief.php");
     include_once ("../classes/group.php");
     include_once ("../classes/user.php");

     @session_start();
     //get all the messages of the current logged in user
     requirelogin();
     $user = $_SESSION['user'];
     $result = $user->getIsAuthenticated();
     if (!$result) {
       header( "Location: ./index.php" );
     } else {

       $brief = $_SESSION['brief'];

       if($brief != null){
?>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border = 1>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" id="topHeader" width="126"><img src="../images/header_front.gif" alt="Welcome to the Department of GVPT" title="Welcome to the Department of GVPT" height="37" width="166" /></td>
    <td colspan="2" id="topBanner"><a href="/gvpt/"><img src="../images/gvpt_title.gif" alt="Government and Politics Homepage" title="Government and Politics Homepage" height="38" width="453" border=0 /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor=#c3c3c3>
    <td colspan="3" id="redBannerTop" align="right"> <?php
        include_once ("../classes/user.php") ;
        if(isset($user)) {
            echo 'Welcome <b>'.$user->getFirstname().' '.$user->getLastname().'</b>';}
        ?>

<a class = "link" href="./logout.php" target="_top"><span class="headerlink"> Logout</span></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h3 align=center>Brief Description</h3>
           <table>
                  <tr><td width="90%">
                          <table align=center border=1>
                          <!--changed $brief->getbriefdescription() to $brief->getBriefId()-->
                             <tr><td><?php echo $brief->getBriefId()?></td></tr>
                          </table>
                      </td>
                      <td width="10%" align="right">
                          <table width=100% >
                             <tr><td><a onclick="MM_openBrWindow('viewbrief.php','','')" href=#>View Brief</a></td></tr>

                          </table>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
           </table>
</body>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Already tried to see online posts but no help. Tried caching but don't see any issue with conf files. 
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to check your error log. Also, I highly recommend installing your own stack for a production server. If I recall correctly, XAMPP is really made for development and not for a production environment.

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked. Actually there was some problem between the database and Apache connection. Resolved.